# Ver toda lista de projetos criados do Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Não conheço muito o ambiente do Intellij. Mas, o que eu realmente queria saber é como posso ver todos os projetos que criei, como no ambiente do Eclipse.

Abaixo, só aparece um projeto, o qual eu criei.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu fechar o programa e inicia-lo novamente, vai estar a mesma coisa.

Comment: Você quer tipo um Workspace no Intellij IDEA, é isto?

Comment: Sim! exatamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Eclipse tem o conceito de Workspace, onde você pode importar vários projetos para um mesmo Workspace e visualizar todos eles ao mesmo tempo.

O Intellij IDEA tem uma alternativa que não tem o nome de Workspace, mas o objetivo é o mesmo. Para isto, você precisa criar um projeto vazio:

```
New Project > Empty Project
```

Depois disto você só precisa importar os projetos (no seu caso, começando pelo `BuildTools`) como **módulos** deste projeto vazio, simulando um Workspace.